# A general word meaning the opposite of 'expired'?

Tags: word-request, adjectives, antonyms

As in 'This food is not expired' or 'I recently renewed my membership so it is not expired'. A word I could use in place of 'not expired' in both these sentences (so not words like 'edible' or 'valid' which are too specific).

Comment: Not a single word, but "still good" would work where I'm from. "This food is still good" and "I recently renewed my membership so it is still good" both make sense to me

Comment: Why is "valid" too specific? Your membership is *valid* until it expires. If you are asking for antonyms of "expire" in general, you should check a dictionary first add what you found (or didn't find).

Comment: How about "in date", or simply "unexpired"?

Comment: @elmer007 still good works, though I realise now I'm looking for something more formal

Comment: @user3169 'This food is valid' wouldn't work, though valid would work in most cases, I checked Thesarus.com but it had only antonyms for the verb (e.g. 'begin')

Comment: @JavaLatte I think unexpired is what I'm looking for, thanks

Comment: For membership, passport or driving licence you can also use "current".

Comment: Current was my first thought for a membership, passport, etc. The way I use it, current also implies that you have met all of the requirements for the membership/passport/license to be valid, for example, you have paid your membership dues. An expired license is definitely not current, but an unexpired license may not be current (just in case that matters to the way you want to use it). @JavaLatte

Comment: fresh? Doesn't have to be specifically related to food

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite is simply *unexpired*. Not used very frequently, but it is a real word.

More common usages are either more specific (e.g. *fresh* as opposed to *expired* when talking about food spoiling), or use more words (e.g. *still good*, which is probably used more often than *unexpired* to mean the same, but is rather informal).

Answer (score 4):

How about *active*?

Though I would consider using *inactive* as the opposite in this case.

P.S. Last time I used *effective* as the opposite of *expired* for a price object (in programming)

Answer (score 0):

As for passports, identification cards, licenses, etc, the word that comes to my mind is "issued". Then again, if something isn't "expired" it must be "valid".